# Sign extending to 32 bits, starting with n bits - C

Tags: c, bit

I am new to C and getting some practice with bit manipulation.

Suppose I have an n bit two's complement number such that n > 0 and n < 31. If I know the size of n in advance, how can I sign extend it to 32 bits?

If n was 16 bits,

```
int32_t extendMe(int16_t n) {
    return (int32_t) n;
}
```

assuming I have the data definitions.

Suppose I have an n bit value that I want to sign extend to 32, how can I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to operate on two's complement numbers regardless of the representation of negative numbers your compiler uses? Or was this just an assumption? If you really mean the former, you must use **unsigned** types for full control over all the (value) bits.

Comment: Ahh yes that is what I meant.

Comment: That typically happens automatically as part of [integer promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions), for example when the compiler does the [usual arithmetic conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions).

Comment: Yep, if you don't care for the representation (two's complement is **very** common, but not guaranteed), you don't have to do anything. Converting the value works as expected.

Comment: Okay so regardless of how many bits n is (assuming > 0 and < 31) return (int32_t) n should behave as expected?

Comment: @Kyle It's really hard to understand this question. If you have an `int16_t` or `int8_t`-> of course. If on the other hand this IS about handling some bit pattern that is a representation of a number in two's complement, but **not** one of your types. you should hold it in an unsigned integer type and access the bits as appropriate (in this case, you would **know** the representation, right?)

Comment: The explicit cast is not needed, but yes it should work as expected.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I see! Thank you!

Comment: `intNN_t` is guaranteed to be 2's complement

Comment: @M.M hmm indeed, so a simpler answer would be possible ... well, mine would still work with just (`unsigned`) `int` ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "assuming I have the data definitions"

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yes, my answer is simpler than yours :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this really is about interpreting arbitrary bit patterns as numbers represented in *n* bits using two's complement, here's some sloppy example code doing that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

// this assumes the number is in the least significant `bits`, with
// the most significat of these being the sign bit.
int32_t fromTwosComplement(uint32_t pattern, unsigned int bits)
{
    // read sign bit
    int negative = !!(pattern & (1U << (bits-1)));

    // bit mask for all bits *except* the sign bit
    uint32_t mask = (1U << (bits-1)) - 1;

    // extract value without sign
    uint32_t val = pattern & mask;

    if (negative)
    {
        // if negative, apply two's complement
        val ^= mask;
        ++val;
        return -val;
    }
    else
    {
        return val;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%" PRId32 "\n", fromTwosComplement(0x1f, 5)); // output -1
    printf("%" PRId32 "\n", fromTwosComplement(0x01, 5)); // output 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An n-bit 2's complement number is negative if bit n - 1 is 1. In that case you want to fill all the bits from n to 31 with 1's. If it's zero, for completeness, you might also want to fill the bits from n to 31 with 0. So you need a mask, that you can use with bit operations to accomplish the above. This is easy to make. Assuming your n bit 2's complement number is held in a uint32_t:

```
int32_t signExtend(uint32_t number, int n)
{
    uint32_t ret;
    uint32_t mask = 0xffffffff << n;
    if (number & (1 << (n - 1)) != 0)
    {
        // number is negative
        ret = number | mask;
    }
    else 
    {
        // number is positive
        ret = number & ~mask;
    }
    return (int32_t) ret;
}
```

Completely untested and the last line might be UB but it should work on most implementations.

Answer (score 0):

5 years and only branching examples are in the answers? Ok, here we go:

```c
#include "stdint.h"
#include "assert.h"

/** Convert a bit pattern as n-bit two's complement number up to 32 bits */
int32_t sgnext32(uint32_t pattern, int nbits)
{
    assert(nbits > 0 && nbits <= 32);
    uint32_t sgnbit = 1L << (nbits - 1);
    uint32_t lsmask = sgnbit | (sgnbit - 1);
    return (int32_t)((pattern + sgnbit) & lsmask) - sgnbit;
}
```

What we do here is we bring two's complement pattern from its `<MIN_INT, MAX_INT>` range to `<0, MAX_UINT>` range by adding `abs(MIN_INT)` (`sgnbit`), then we clip it to only n-bits (`lsmask`) and restoring the two's complement content, but in 32-bit space.
This works for `nbits = 32` too, because in this instance 32-bit overflow works exactly like the mask we apply.

```c
int main()
{
    assert((int32_t) 0 == sgnext32(0, 1));
    assert((int32_t) -1 == sgnext32(1, 1));

    assert((int32_t) 0 == sgnext32(0, 2));
    assert((int32_t) 1 == sgnext32(1, 2));
    assert((int32_t) -1 == sgnext32(3, 2));
    assert((int32_t) -2 == sgnext32(2, 2));

    assert((int32_t) 0 == sgnext32(0, 15));
    assert((int32_t) 0x3fff == sgnext32(0x3fff, 15));
    assert((int32_t) -0x4000 == sgnext32(0x4000, 15));
    assert((int32_t) -1 == sgnext32(0x7fff, 15));
    assert((int32_t) -2 == sgnext32(0x7ffe, 15));

    assert((int32_t) 0 == sgnext32(0, 24));
    assert((int32_t) 0x7fffff == sgnext32(0x7fffff, 24));
    assert((int32_t) -0x800000 == sgnext32(0x800000, 24));
    assert((int32_t) -1 == sgnext32(0xffffff, 24));
    assert((int32_t) -2 == sgnext32(0xfffffe, 24));

    assert((int32_t) 0 == sgnext32(0, 32));
    assert((int32_t) 0x7fffffff == sgnext32(0x7fffffff, 32));
    assert((int32_t) -0x80000000 == sgnext32(0x80000000, 32));
    assert((int32_t) -1 == sgnext32(0xffffffff, 32));
    assert((int32_t) -2 == sgnext32(0xfffffffe, 32));
    return 0;
}
```